# Which MPI library are packages linked against? Open MPI?

Tags: compiling, libraries, shared-library, mpi, dynamic-linking

Some packages in the Ubuntu repositories provide pre-compiled binaries of shared libraries (`*.so`). For example, the package [`fftw2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fftw2) provides the FFTW library (version 2), including the MPI-related library files `/usr/lib/libfftw_mpi.so.2` and `/usr/lib/librfftw_mpi.so.2`. This evokes the question of which of the numerous MPI libraries these files are actually linked against. On my system (`amd64`), `ldd /usr/lib/libfftw_mpi.so.2` shows

> ```
>   linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd80ba4000)
>   libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2c3fe22000)
>   libmpi.so.20 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so.20 (0x00007f2c3fb30000)
>   […]
> ```

So they seem to point to Open MPI, whose files are called `libmpi.so` on Ubuntu.

I have found the [`mpi-default-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mpi-default-dev) metapackage, whose description is

> This metapackage depends on the development files of the recommended
>   MPI implementation for each platform, currently Open MPI on all of the
>   platforms where it exists, and MPICH on the others. The package which
>   this depends on has alternatives links for the shared libraries libmpi
>   and libmpi++, and for compilers mpicc, mpic++/mpicxx/mpiCC, mpif77 and
>   mpi90 and their manpages.

And indeed, on `amd64`, this pulls in Open MPI. However, does that mean that **all** libraries using MPI in the Ubuntu repositories are necessarily compiled with/linked against Open MPI?